# Cannot Deploy Lighting Web Component with Opportunity Contact Roles

Tags: lightning-web-components, opportunitycontactrole, lwc-xml

I'm trying to deploy a simple component for `OpportunityContactRoles` but I am not able to deploy the Meta data necessary to expose the component to the Opportunity Record Page. I've tried just exposing the meta data, and also attempted to only do the record page, but the deployment keeps failing with a loglevel fatal.

#### Apex

Method is `getOpportunityContactRoles`

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static List<OpportunityContactRole> getOpportunityContactRoles(String oppId){
        OpportunityContactRole[] ocrs = [
            SELECT
                ContactId,
                CreatedById,
                LastModifiedById,
                OpportunityId,
                isPrimary,
                Role
            FROM OpportunityContactRole
            WHERE OpportunityId =: oppId
        ];
        return ocrs;
```

#### JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getOpportunityContactRoles from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityDataHandler.getOpportunityContactRoles';

export default class OpportunityContactRolesList extends LightningElement {

    @wire(getOpportunityContactRoles) ocrs;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card
        title="ApexWireMethodToProperty"
        icon-name="custom:custom63"
    >
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={ocrs.data}>
                <template for:each={ocrs.data} for:item="ocr">
                    <p key={ocr.Id}>{ocr.Name}</p>
                </template>
            </template>
            <template if:true={ocrs.error}>

                <p>ERROR ERROR ERROR</p>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

#### Meta

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>49.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>

</LightningComponentBundle>
```

#### Errors

```
--json --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 1
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava there were no errors. The only error is --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 1

Comment: Look into deployment status in the org. From the set up you will find deployment status